# Error con Nusoap PHP

Tags: php, webservice, nusoap

Tengo este error al momento de querer ver el WSDL:
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Esta es la función:

```
<?php
function getUserByName($name){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userdb");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Error al conectar al a base de datos'. mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where name like '%$name%'");
    $retStr="";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $response[]=$row;
        }
        return json_encode($response);
    }else{
        return "no existen datos";
    }
}
```

Aqui llamo a la libreria

```
require"./lib/nusoap.php";
$server = new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("soap PHP Demo", "urn:soapdemo");
$server->register(
            "getUserByName",
                array("name"=>"xsd:string"),
                array("return"=>"xsd:string"));
$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

adjunto el codigo para ver si hay algun error

Comment: Hola por favor coloca el código y los mensajes de error como texto, no en capturas de imagen, que hacen más difícil analizar o reproducir el problema. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, ya eh corregido

Comment: Muéstranos el XML que se estaría generando, es muy probable que el mismo sea inválido o esté vacío.